# Linker script in .so file? (libc.so) Is that right?

Tags: linux, python, arm, elf, linker

I am currently trying to get python to run on my NAS which is a Zyxel NSA325.

I did manage to get python 2.7 and pip running and I was able to successfully install the watchdog module with pip. I followed [these instructions](http://forum.nas-central.org/viewtopic.php?f=249&t=10879) to get python and pip running btw.

When I run a python script that uses the watchdog module I get a weir error, tough.

```
/usr/local/zy-pkgs/ffproot/ffp/bin/python2.7: '/ffp/lib/libc.so' is not an ELF file
```

I googled what the header of a ELF file is supposed to look like and [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) it starts with `7f 45 4c 46` which translates to `.ELF`. So I did a quick `cat /ffp/lib/libc.so` and the result was:

```
/* GNU ld script
 * Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
 * the static library, so try that secondarily. */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-bigarm",
         "elf32-littlearm")
GROUP ( libc.so.0 uclibc_nonshared.a AS_NEEDED ( ld-uClibc.so.0 ) )
```

Clearly this is not an ELF file. So I spent some more time researching and I think it is a [linker script](http://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts).

But now I'm out of ideas. Why is there a linker script in a .so file? Is that right? How can I fix it?

System info:

```
# uname -a
Linux NSA325-v2 2.6.31.8 #2 Fri Jun 23 11:03:47 CST 2017 armv5tel GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 17):

When you see a file named `.so`, it’s not necessarily a shared library. These files are used when linking a program at build-time, not run-time; they are commonly symlinks to the real shared library, but at least on systems using GNU `ld` they can also be linker scripts, and that’s perfectly OK. If you look on a modern glibc-based system you’ll find that `libc.so` is a linker script there too.

That doesn’t explain why Python (or the watchdog module) is looking for `libc.so` instead of `libc.so.0`... It could be a mis-configuration of the Python interpreter perhaps, or an invalid assumption in the watchdog module. I’ll take a look at the latter later today; if it’s the former, you’d be better off asking on the forum you linked to in your question.

Comment: I had this problem too for a special JNI library which looked for libxxx.so files as well. The JAVA environment can not load these kind of scripted libraries. Is there a way around this system wise or is the vendor of the library responsible to avoid such a behaviour of the libs?

Comment: I reckon that the JNI library should be fixed — it should either load libraries by soname (typically `libxxx.so.N`), or embed the library it expects in its JAR file.